# Search for different models in one page with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using express and mongoose to list cats in my home page

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    Model.cats.find(function(err, ret) {
        res.render('home.jade', {cats: ret});
    })
});
```

Now lets say I wanted to display cats **and dogs** as well. How could I do it? The find function is async after all, so Im not sure how to prepare the response.

Comment: Don't know a thing about mongoose, but don't let asynchronicity stop you, do take a look at the https://github.com/caolan/async module, it will sure ease your life sooner or later. Most likely sooner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include the `async` [npm module](https://github.com/caolan/async), it's quite simple:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    async.parallel({
        cats: function(callback) {
            Model.cats.find(function(err, ret) {
                callback(null, ret);
            });
        },
        dogs: function(callback) {
            Model.dogs.find(function(err, ret) {
                callback(null, ret);
            });
        }
    },
    function(err, results) {
        // results will be { cats: results, dogs: results}
        res.render('home.jade', results);
    });  
});
```

The technique above starts two named async requests, one `cat` and the other `dog`. Each function calls your `Model`s. When complete, they call the `callback` passing any errors (which I've just put as `null` above) and the results of the find. It's quite handy when using named calls this way as the results will be placed in two properties of a single object which you could pass directly to the `render` method.